# How to make a POST request with input text as data React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to make a POST request using text field data, can anyone help me with how to store that input and make a request after a button is pressed.

I attempted to use `useRef()` which allowed me to obtain the data however I was not able to store it as a data object to then persist.

Currently my data persists, however it persists an empty object and the state is not being updated.

If anyone can help, I will really appreciate that.

Below is my `App.js` class

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/artists"
});

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        artists: [],
        theArtistName: ""
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.getArtists()
    }

    //calling this method will allow artist array to be populated everytime an event occurs, e.g POST, PUT, DELETE
    getArtists = async () =>{
        let data = await api.get("/").then(({ data }) => data);
        this.setState({artists: data}) //setting our artists to be the data we fetch
    }

    createArtist = async () =>{
       let response = await api.post('/', {name: this.state.theArtistName})
        console.log(response)
        this.getArtists()
    }

    deleteArtist = async (id) =>{
        let data = await api.delete('/${id}')
        this.getArtists();
    }

    handleAddArtist = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            theArtistName: event.target.value
        })
        const data = this.state.theArtistName
        console.log(data)

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.createArtist()

    }

    render(){
        // const {theArtistName} = this.state
        return(
            <>           
            <input type={Text} placeholder="Enter Artist Name" name="theArtistName"></input>
                <button onClick={this.createArtist}>Add Artist</button>
                    {this.state.artists.map(artist => <h4 key={artist.id}>{artist.name}
                <button onClick={() =>this.deleteArtist(artist.id)}>Delete artist</button></h4>)}
            </>
        )
        
    }

}


export default App;
```

Comment: redux form makes this extremely easy. check out the documentation here https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, `useRef` is a hook only meant for function components and not for class components. For using Refs in class components use `React.createRef()`.

Usually, HTML input elements maintain their own state. The usual way to access the value of an input element from a React component that renders it is to control the input element's state via this component by adding an `onChange` listener and a `value` attribute to the input element:

```js
class App extends Component{
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {artistName: ""};
        this.handleArtistNameChange = this.handleArtistNameChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleArtistNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({artistName: event.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return (     
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.artistName}
                onChange={this.handleArtistNameChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Whenever the value of the input element changes the `App` component will rerender with the most up-to-date value of the input in its state.

Here is a working example:

[image: Edit flamboyant-noether-19tfl]

You can read more on using form elements in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Comment: he don't need to bind the method he's using arrow function which bind automatically to it closest context

Comment: @adel Well, this is true regarding the code Joshua provided in his question, but not regarding the example in my answer since I'm not using an arrow function.

Comment: hey Befeepilf thank you for your answer to my question, i added it to my code however i am still having trouble to persist, it does not persist with this code, I will look into your initial comment more and aim to solve the problem, 

Comment: @Joshua Check out the example I added to my answer. Make sure to read all the comments I added to the code.

Comment: Amazing, thank you everyone for your help. Befeepilf thank you very much you solved my problem! CodeSandBox is amazing as well.

Answer (score 0):

because react update state asynchronously so when you are invoking `handleAddArtist` function which update state the event might be gone so you need to store the value from the event in variable like this :

```
handleAddArtist = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    const {value} = e.target
    this.setState({
        theArtistName: value
    })
}
```

and to check state update there is a lifecycle method called `componentDidUpdate` for class component and `useEffect` for functional component.

[edit]:
call `this.createArtist()` in `componentDidUpdate` like this :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
if(prevState.theArtistName!==this.state.theArtistName)
this.createArtist()
}
```

so the `createArtist` will fire only when  `theArtistName` state change.

Comment: hey thank you for your help adel, i tried this however no event occurs after the button 'Add artist' is clicked. Whenever i reload the page myself another  "Delete artist" button keeps appearing on the scene and is persisting as an empty object to my database.

Comment: you cant invoke `this.createArtist()` immediately after `this.seState` because setSatet fire asynchronously, instead you should fire `this.createArtist()` in  `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method which will fire immediatly after state change. check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is an async function, it takes second argument as callback. This should solve your problem. i.e.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/artists",
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      artists: [],
      theArtistName: "",
    };
  }

  //calling this method will allow artist array to be populated everytime an event occurs, e.g POST, PUT, DELETE
  getArtists = async () => {
    let data = await api.get("/").then(({ data }) => data);
    this.setState({ artists: data }); //setting our artists to be the data we fetch
  };

  createArtist = async () => {
    let response = await api.post("/", { name: this.state.theArtistName });
    console.log(response);
    this.getArtists();
  };

  deleteArtist = async (id) => {
    let data = await api.delete("/${id}");
    this.getArtists();
  };

  handleAddArtist = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        theArtistName: event.target.value,
      },
      () => {
        this.createArtist();
      }
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getArtists();
  }

  render() {
    // const {theArtistName} = this.state
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type={Text}
          placeholder="Enter Artist Name"
          name="theArtistName"
        ></input>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddArtist}>Add Artist</button>
        {this.state.artists.map((artist) => (
          <h4 key={artist.id}>
            {artist.name}
            <button onClick={() => this.deleteArtist(artist.id)}>
              Delete artist
            </button>
          </h4>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for helping, I tried this but it did not persist actual data, only empty data is persisted